# Does Gridsearch CV shuffle the data before creating the folds?

Tags: scikit-learn, shuffle

I'm used sklearn GridsearchCV to tune hyperparameters but want to know if the dataset I give it will be shuffled before the folds are created. I'd like it to NOT be shuffled but I can't find if it is or isn't in the documentation. Something like train_test_split has a boolean to shuffle or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, GridSearchCV will use a clean StratifiedKFold or KFold cross-validator. The default for these cross-validators is `shuffle=False`. The `cv` parameter documentation of GridSearchCV provides some additional information, too.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation)

> ### 3.1.3. A note on shuffling
>
> If the data ordering is not arbitrary (e.g. samples with the same class label are contiguous), shuffling it first may be essential to get a meaningful cross- validation result. However, the opposite may be true if the samples are not independently and identically distributed. For example, if samples correspond to news articles, and are ordered by their time of publication, then shuffling the data will likely lead to a model that is overfit and an inflated validation score: it will be tested on samples that are artificially similar (close in time) to training samples.
>
> Some cross validation iterators, such as KFold, have an inbuilt option to shuffle the data indices before splitting them. Note that:
>
> This consumes less memory than shuffling the data directly.
>
> By default no shuffling occurs, including for the (stratified) K fold cross- validation performed by specifying cv=some_integer to cross_val_score, grid search, etc. Keep in mind that train_test_split still returns a random split.
>
> The random_state parameter defaults to None, meaning that the shuffling will be different every time KFold(..., shuffle=True) is iterated. However, GridSearchCV will use the same shuffling for each set of parameters validated by a single call to its fit method.
>
> To get identical results for each split, set random_state to an integer.